# How does the combined ticket work in Agra?

Tags: tickets, india

[I've read](http://www.ixigo.com/agra-fort-agra-india-ne-1000190) that when you buy a ticket to entry to the Taj Majal you get a "INR 500 for a one-time composite toll levied by Agra Development Authority for Taj Mahal, Agra Fort, Itimadi-ud-daula, Akbar’s Tomb, Sikandara and Fatehpur Sikri". How does it work? It means that if I pay 750 INR to get into the Taj Majal I don't have to pay to enter in the other places? And if that's true, I have to go the same day or the entrance is valid for the next day?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's bureaucratic and complicated.  (It's India!)

Each of the sites has a *ticket*, plus there's also a *levy*, and you need to pay both to get in.  Each ticket is valid for one entry to that site only, and seems to be standardized at Rs 250 per site.  The levy varies in value between Rs 10 and 500, but if you pay the maximum levy for the Taj Mahal, it's valid everywhere else as well *for the same day only*.

Examples:

1. You visit the Taj Mahal in the morning and Agra Fort in the afternoon.  You need to pay Rs 250 for the Taj Mahal ticket, Rs 250 for the Agra Fort ticket, and Rs 500 for the combined levy, for a total of **1000 rupees**.
2. You visit the Taj Mahal and Agra Fort on separate days.  Like case 1, you still need to pay Rs 750 for the Taj ticket and its levy plus Rs 250 for the Agra Fort, but since your levy only covers one day you now need to fork out additional 50 rupees for the Agra Fort's levy, total **1050 rupees**.
3. Rendered insane by heatstroke, you decide to skip the Taj Mahal and only visit the Fort and Fatehpur Sikri.  You pay Rs 250 each for tickets plus levies of Rs 50 and Rs 10 respectively, a total of **560 rupees**.

Comment: "Rendered insane by heatstroke" - I loved that! :D